# I have generated a diff file using the diff command, how do I view it in Intellij's "Differences Viewer"?

Tags: intellij-idea, diff

I have a diff file I've created with the cygwin diff command.  I named it "output.diff".  I like the way [the Intellij Differences Viewer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/comparing-files.html) works, so I'd like to view the differences there, but when I double click on the file, it opens it as a text file.  Is there a way to have Intellij open the diff file in the Differences Viewer?

Comment: If you want to use IntelliJ to view diffs, don't use cygwin to generate the diff file. Rather, let intelliJ compare the two files you have used to create the diff file, as per the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in the project explorer press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select the two files. Then just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> . it will pop up the difference viewer.

Comment: What if, hypothetically, I don't have the 2 files?

Comment: If you don't have at least 2 files, you don't have any differences.